# Correct steps to choose a Threading model in java

Tags: multithreading, profiling, threadpool

1) I am working on the title of my question which is the correct path/steps I should undertake and understand to choose the correct threading model for my application.

2) I have a Linux machine whose /proc/cpuinfo file gives me the following information
a) No. of physical processors:- 2
b) No. of cpucores :- 6
c) No. of virtual processors:-24

I have around 5 JVM processes(of the same application) running on the same machine. Every process has 3 threads, one which polls for a new event(Thread A), one which queries the Database(Thread B, round about 20 queries for each event), One which publishes the event Data(Thread C). 1 LinkedBlockingQueue connect Thread A and Thread B, another connects Thread B and Thread C.

**Each event is independent of another**. I want to leverage this statement and hence would like to go for thread pool where more threads of type Thread B can be introduced and they parallely withdraw the data and send them to Thread C.

What I have done till now:-

1) Nothing much, I am deciding on the right strategy. 
2) I went through the following blog 
http://codeidol.com/java/java-concurrency/Applying-Thread-Pools/Sizing-Thread-Pools/
3) The formula described there wants me to compute N/C, ratio of wait time to compute time. For the same I have decided to use Netbeans profiler remotely and analyze both the thread activity and the method level instrumentation.
4) However the same does not give me CPU usage, so I am planning to use Visual VM's monitor tab to analyze the CPU usage.
5) I am aware about the fact that scaling of threads will need require more cumulative stack memory.
6) The number of Database connections at anytime may not be a problem, but I have to check on the same.

Am I following the right path ?  Especially I need advice because there are multiple JVM processes, so I am getting more confused in terms of analysis?

Thanks

Comment: Still No takers for the question!

Comment: I need suggestions, please review the steps and let me know!

Comment: I am surprised, that I haven't received a single comment!!